# django query set for more than one model

Tags: python, django

I am working for search in django and I am not able to find if I can able to use two different models in same app in results of that query set.

For eg. I am making search as shown but the fields `authors` and `title` are from different models what should I do at line `results = Books.object...` where `Books` is for model name. 
my original views:

```
from django.db.models import Q
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response 
from bills.models import *

def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q', '')
    if query:
        qset = (
            Q(expenses__rate_of_pure__icontains=query) |
            Q(expenses__customer_id__icontains=query) |
            Q(Choice__carat__icontains=query)  |
            Q(Choice__labour_cost__icontains=query)  |
            Q(Choice__item__icontains=query)  |
            Q(Choice__weight__icontains=query)
        )
        results = expenses.objects.filter(qset).distinct()   
    else:
        results = []
    return render_to_response("bills/search.html", {"results": results,
                                              "query": query})
```

and models are:

```
from django.db import models
from front.models import category
class expenses(models.Model): 
    purchase_order_no = models.IntegerField(max_length=3,\
                                            primary_key=True)  
    rate_of_pure = models.IntegerField(max_length=15)
    voucher = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    customer_id = models.ForeignKey(category)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return'%s' % (self.purchase_order_no)

class Choice(models.Model):
    customer_id  = models.ForeignKey(expenses, unique=False, blank=True,  
    null=True) 
    carat = models.IntegerField(max_length=2)
    item = models.CharField(max_length=25) 
    weight = models.FloatField(max_length=10) 
    labour_cost = models.IntegerField(max_length=10)
```

the thing I want to ask is in views line 16, where i have to give the name of models which model should i give as i am using two parts of the model.

Comment: Can you paste your above models here?

Comment: please indend your lines after `if` condition

Comment: Shrinath , I am not having these actual views this was an example and I want to fill the query set with variables from two different models of the same app, I am not getting which model to use for objects.all query

Comment: But what problem do you have? You've described what you're trying to accomplish (but not clear for me) and pasted some code that (in my opinion) works how you're expecting. Try to explain what problem do you have with that code and what part of it makes some troubles for you.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you might be looking for this

```
results = Book.objects.filter(qset).distinct().values('authors', 'title')
```

`QuerySet.values` will return only the fields you are looking for, which in this case will return the `title` with associated `authors`. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values)